# form only submits a post when form is empty problem

Tags: php, html, css, forms, post

Hello im trying to make a form that uploads a video file with images, tags and video name (vn stands for video name). which would upload all of this with a press of a button with post. while this worked in the past currently it isnt working and instead stops without uploading the data through post, however when i present the form with empty inputs it decides to go through with the post but then gets caught with the check if the forms are filled.
below is the code

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="btn">

    <label>
       Choose Your Video <input type="file" id="file" name="file" hidden="">
        </label><br><br><br><br></div>
        <div class="btn1">
<label>
       Choose Your cover image <input type="file" id="images" name="image" hidden="">
        </label></div>
       

        <input type="text" placeholder="tags" onclick="" name="tags" id="tags" class="textbox">
 
 <input type="text" placeholder="video name" name="vn" class="textbox1">
<div class="ca">
    <label>
  upload <input  type="submit" name="submit2345" hidden="">
        </div></label>  
</form>
```

php (not all of it just the bits you need, im not showing all of it because it spreads across many lines). The check for the video file is lower and i haven't implemented a cover image yet because of this problem

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit2345"]))
{
  
    header1("eee");
    If(rtrim($_POST['tags'])!="#" && rtrim($_POST['vn']!= "" )){
```

css if it matters

```
#vupb{
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 40%), 8px 2px 16px rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding-top: 30vh;
    width: 30vw;
    margin-left: 30vw;
    margin-top: 2vh;
    padding-bottom: 10vh;
 }
 .ca{
      width: 20vw;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 0px solid lightgrey;
      background-color: limegreen;
      color:white;
      font-weight: 1000;
      font-size: large;
      margin-left: 5vw;
      margin-top: 5vh;
      padding-top: 2vh;
      padding-bottom: 2vh;
    }
    .ca:hover{
      background-color: #2bb32b;
      color: lavender;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
 
    .login input[type=file]{
    display:none;
    }
    .btn{
        width: 7vw;
        height: 5vh;
      padding-top: 1vh;
      padding-bottom: 1vh;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 0px solid black;
      background-color: #1877f2;
      color:white;
      font-weight: 1000;
      font-size:medium;     
      margin-left: 18vw;
      margin-top: -33.5vh;
            }
            .btn:hover{
                background-color: #186edf;
      color: lavender;
      cursor: pointer;
            }
            .vfi {
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 12vw;
                height: 14vh;
                overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-x: hidden;
                text-align: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
                margin-left: 5vw;
                margin-top: -20vh;
                font-weight: bold;
                z-index: 90;
            }
            .textbox {
      width: 20vw;
      height: 7vh;
      font-size: medium;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid lightgrey;
      margin-top: 15vh;
    }
    .textbox1 {
      width: 20vw;
      height: 7vh;
      font-size: medium;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid lightgrey;
      margin-top: 2vh;
    }
    
    
    
    .btn1{
        width: 7vw;
        height: 5vh;
      padding-top: 1vh;
      padding-bottom: 1vh;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 0px solid black;
      background-color: #1877f2;
      color:white;
      font-weight: 1000;
      font-size:medium;     
      margin-left: 18vw;
      margin-top: 12.5vh;
   
            }
            .btn1:hover{
                background-color: #186edf;
      color: lavender;
      cursor: pointer;
            }
            .vfi1 {
                border: 1px solid black;
                width: 12vw;
                height: 14vh;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                text-align: center;
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                background-size: 100% 100%;
                margin-left: 5vw;
                margin-top: 5vh;
                font-weight: bold;
                z-index: 91;
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "form only submits a post when form is empty..."? Does it not go into the main if statement, or does it stop within that if statement? Also, what are the `hidden=""` attrs in your fields? You should remove them unless you have a good reason to keep them.

Comment: Is that all of your php ?  The html from it is incomplete and invalid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your HTML isn't valid. Most likely your POST isn't working because there are several syntax errors. Try again by using valid HTML like this

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="btn">
        <label>
            Choose Your Video
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" hidden=""/>
        </label>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <br/>
    </div>

    <div class="btn1">
        <label>
            Choose Your cover image
            <input type="file" id="images" name="image" hidden=""/>
        </label>
    </div>

    <input type="text" placeholder="tags" onclick="" name="tags" id="tags" class="textbox"/>

    <input type="text" placeholder="video name" name="vn" class="textbox1"/>

    <div class="ca">
        <label>
            upload
            <input type="submit" name="submit2345" hidden=""/>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: oh my gosh i was stuck on this for a while and you saved me thanks so much!!!

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it is the solution

Comment: yes i have set it as accepted

Comment: sure? don't see it as accepted

Comment: has it came in now?